# Why is the class of summary(summary.lm) "summaryDefault" "table"

Tags: r, lm, summary

I have a linear model:
   `linearMod <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars) summary(linearMod)`
All OK, and:

```
   summary(summary(linearMod))
              Length Class  Mode   
call           3     -none- call   
terms          3     terms  call   
residuals     50     -none- numeric
coefficients   8     -none- numeric
aliased        2     -none- logical
sigma          1     -none- numeric
df             3     -none- numeric
r.squared      1     -none- numeric
adj.r.squared  1     -none- numeric
fstatistic     3     -none- numeric
cov.unscaled   4     -none- numeric
```

BUT

```
    class(summary(summary(linearMod)))
[1] "summaryDefault" "table"
```

Please how do I access the fstatistic, which is what I want

I expected to be able to use

```
    sr <- summary(summary(linearMod))
    sr$fstatistic
```

But I get

```
    summary(summary(linearMod))$fstatistic
Error in summary(summary(linearMod))$fstatistic : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `summary(linearMod)$fstatistic`.  Putting another `summary()` around `summary(linearMod)` generates a list-like object which is a summary of the summary!

```r
> linearMod <- lm(mpg~ hp, mtcars)
> class(linearMod)
[1] "lm"
> class(summary(linearMod))
[1] "summary.lm"
> class(summary(summary(linearMod)))
[1] "summaryDefault" "table"
```